# problems with """input().split() in loop""" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, io, output

```
n, m, k, r = tuple([int(i) for i in input().split()])

roads = []

for road in range(m):
    t = tuple(list(map(int, input().split())))
    roads.append(t)

print(roads)
```

My input is this:

```
6 6 2 6
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
3 5
```

I expected that output would be: `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (3, 5)]`

but output is this: `[(), (0, 1), (), (1, 2), (), (2, 3)]`

Why?

Comment: are you sure you have saved file and running the same code, as I get your expected answer only.

Comment: How are you running the python file?

Comment: I use Pycharm environment.

Comment: Unrelated, you don't need to pass a list to `tuple`; it can accept an arbitrary iterable. `tuple(int(i) for i in input.split())` and `t = tuple(map(int, input().split()))` are both fine.